# Как сделать так, чтобы таймер не останавливался при блокировке устройства?

Tags: java, android

Есть таймер - класс андроида, который каждую минуту выполняет определенное действие. Но обнаружилась такая проблема: при блокировке устройства таймер перестает работать и возобновляет свою работу только после разблокировки.
Запуск таймера происходит в сервисе:

```
nearestTime = changeDB.getNearestSimpleAlarmTime();
if (mTimer != null) {
    mTimer.cancel();
    mTimer.purge();
    mTimer = null;
}
if (nearestTime.getHour() > -1) {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int seconds = 60 - calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    System.out.println("первая проверка через " + seconds + " секунд");
    mTimer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new SimpleTimer(nearestTime, getApplicationContext());
    mTimer.schedule(timerTask, seconds * 1000, 60000);
} else {
    stopSelf();
}
```

тело таймера:

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if (nearestTime.getHour() < hour || (nearestTime.getHour() == hour && nearestTime.getMinute() < minute) || (nearestTime.getHour() == hour && nearestTime.getMinute() == minute)) {
    Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    scheduledIntent.putExtra("hour", nearestTime.getHour());
    scheduledIntent.putExtra("minute", nearestTime.getMinute());
    scheduledIntent.putExtra("fulltime", nearestTime.getFulltime());
    context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);
}
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

P.S. Нужно сделать именно на таймере без AlarmManager.

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей.Где вызывается таймер? В `Activity`, в сервисе, в виджете? Также не помешает фрагмент кода. При текущей формулировке вопроса, сложно что-либо понять.  На будущее, старайтесь, пожалуйста, писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Comment: Простите, исправил